Found duplicate columns in the data to save: neighborhoods SQLSTATE: 42711
I'm trying to overwrite a Delta Lake query on Databricks. The thing is, there is no (apparent) duplicate columns in the dataframe. What this could be?
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE firecallsdelta SELECT *, Neighborhooods_-_Analysis_Boundaries AS Neighborhoods FROM firecallsdelta;
SELECT * FROM firecallsdelta
The error is as follows.
[DELTA_DUPLICATE_COLUMNS_FOUND] Found duplicate columns in the data to save: neighborhoods SQLSTATE: 42711

What is the table structure? Are you sure that there isn't already a neighborhoods column?
